# bootstrap fixed header for mobile device

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a mobile app using phone gap, for CSS i have used Twitter Bootstrap
I need a fixed header on the mobile, the below code does not work and the header is not fixed.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>some thing </li>
                    <li><a href="abc"><i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="./index.html"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="icon-time icon-white"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I saw the below article, it says navbar-fixed-top does not work for mobile devices
any suggestion how could i get a fixed header,

Comment: Have you tried setting `.navbar { position:fixed; }` ?